# Mail 6.5 Activity Indicator LAG

Tags: macos, mail.app

I get frustrated by the huge **lag** (delay) in Mail respond to the request for action.

It takes few seconds or more before it shows to be responding to the request.

Example the request for move mails from one account to another, or rebuild folders, and so on.

The problem is that I do not know if it did accept my request (since there is no instant notification of any sort) so I keep repeating the request till it finally shows up in the Mail Activity window to be doing something.

This is an example only, but it took me like hitting the Rebuild 5x times till it finally showed this indication, so I could go and do something else.

[image]

So the question is is there a way to have the Mail tell me instantly following my request that it has started doing something. Like a spinning weel or anything?

MBA 10.8.4 Mail 6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I could use the Activity Window and keep it on top to see what mail is doing as best solution for now.

[image]